# Shadowing someone vs training for a new job

Tags: difference

After reading a few posts on Reddit by med students and doctors alike I came across the term **"shadowing"** quite often. I am familiar with what it means and I've even dated someone in the medical field before and she would always use that term to mean that someone was getting trained by her, by watching her and mimicking what she does. I've always wondered whether the term **"shadowing"** is only exclusive to the medical field since I have never really heard it anywhere else. Could it be used in a different job setting?
Thanks

Comment: I've even dated someone in the field? What field? shadowing means following someone around to learn from them in just about any profession.

Comment: Medical field (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use *shadowing* in other fields like IT too.  Here's [an article describing its use in other fields](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/job-shadowing-is-effective-on-the-job-training-1919285):

> ...job shadowing is especially effective for jobs such as these:
> Restaurant employees: serving staff, bartenders, cooks, chefs, bus persons, cashiers, hosts.
> ...
> Manufacturing jobs: supervisors, quality control, skilled trades employees, machine operators, tool and die makers, machinists.

But it does not mean exactly the same thing as "training" or "being trained by" and you can't necessarily replace one with the other.  *Shadowing* is a kind of training, but not all training is shadowing.  *Shadowing* means following someone closely, like their shadow, watching what they do.  But training could include something like being assigned formal exercises to do, or being assigned independent tasks to accomplish, which are definitely not "shadowing".